# Any way to find deep string in a object?

Tags: javascript

```
const object = { card: { bank: { id: '123' } } };
```

I need to know if '123' exists in **object**. Any way to do that? Thanks!

Comment: What have you tried ?

Comment: also [Finding value in deep nested array of object, recursively, javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52453666/finding-value-in-deep-nested-array-of-object-recursively-javascript) and [How to find the key of a value in a nested object recursively](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57676477/how-to-find-the-key-of-a-value-in-a-nested-object-recursively)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use recursion and `Array.some` to search deeply for the value

```js
const deepExists = (obj, query) =>
  Object.values(obj).some(v => typeof v === "object" ?
    deepExists(v, query) :
    v === query
  );
  
console.log(deepExists({ card: { bank: { id: "123" }}}, "123"));
```

Comment: Very useful! i'm learning and I did not know the recursion, I will be investigating it. Thank you!!